# Linq to Entity - can i get to another table in the model when in the list template MVC page

Tags: linq, entity-framework, dynamic-data

in the out of the project template solution (Dynamic Data Web Application), I have the model created and all is good. - Get the list of the tables, and the select edit etc.

But my database has linking tables that just contain forgien keys  - so the list template just displays the fk value

[image: diagram of the table]

Is there away to combine the list of the row in the primary table with an inspection of another table based on the fk?

More akin to a join in SQL? but using Linq2Entity and the MetaModel?

Below is the List.aspx.cs - this seems to bind the standard grid to the entitydatasource, but this is to the current table as per the route in the MVC.

But as you can see i need to go and query the Person, Role and Link table via the model to get the other fields so that this would be useful.
[image: vstudio]

PS want to try and keep this in LINQ2Entity if possible  -trying to grok

the natural thing that I want to do is start to spin off new sql queries to go and retrive the values.  But this is not in this idiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can reference the metaModel via the dataContext

```
MetaModel refMetaModel = MetaModel.GetModel(typeof(yourdataContextName));
MetaTable refMetaModel;
refMetaModel =  refMetaModel.GetTable("yourTableName");
```

PS looked at your code and this works in your sceanrio. You can get the tables from the model then inspect the data returned for each table in the model

[MSDN article on the MetaModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.dynamicdata.metamodel.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Uselful to use this as well from the Linq to Entities Model -

Using the dataContext - you can get the acutal data most useful.

The metaModel allows access to the dataModel which gives you the underlying ddl type information

```
//use the datacontext to get the underlying data
      using (brrdbEntities brr = new brr_dbEntities())
      {
          ObjectQuery<person> people = brr.person;
          IQueryable<string> names = from p in people select p.person_name;
          foreach (var name    in names)
```